# Meaning of the /ʌ/ sounds in Nalo Hopkinson's story Can’t Beat ‘Em

Tags: short-stories, nalo-hopkinson

In Nalo Hopkinson's short story [Can’t Beat ‘Em](https://uncannymagazine.com/article/cant-beat-em/), people try to deal with a sort of "sink throat monster" that one of the characters calls "glups".
While reading the story a second time, I gained the impression that the story has a higher-than-usual percentage of words containing the `/ʌ/` sound preceded by an "l" or "m" and followed by an "l", "m", "p" or "g".
(The IPA symbol [`/ʌ/`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_unrounded_vowel) represents the vowel that you find in words such as "gut" and "dull".)
Examples include "glup" (obviously repeated several times), "slug", "glugging", "slugged", "mug" and "glumly".

A number of other words come close enough, e.g. "slung" and "pulsed", however, if I broaden the category too much, the question becomes meaningless, since the syllable structure `consonant(s) + /ʌ/ + consonant(s)` is not unusual.

So my question is whether this syllable structured is indeed unusually frequent here (so far, I've only compared this story with Hopkinson's [Ally](http://www.nightmare-magazine.com/fiction/ally/), where this syllable structure is less frequent) and what it might mean.

Comment: This could be heavily dependent on accent. I wonder what kind of accent the author has (born in Jamaica, lives in Canada, IIRC) and how she'd pronounce these phonemes.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Hmm. How relevant is this if the story (unlike "Shift") is not set in Jamaica or the Caribbean?